# What is the depth of field if the the focus distance is set to infinity?

Tags: depth-of-field, hyperfocal-distance, focus-distance

If the camera format is 35mm, the focal length of the lens is 35mm, the aperture is f/4, the subject distance is 25ft, and the hyperfocal distance is 39'7", then what would be the range of focus when we set the focus to infinity?

Comment: If you focus on infinity, then all objects at or farther away than the hyperfocal distance will be in focus.

Comment: But if you instead focus on an object that is at the hyperfocal distance then all objects from half the hyperfocal distance away till infinity will be in focus, and that's good enough for this case to get the object in focus as well as everything else that's farther away.

Comment: There's a difference between being 'in focus' (only a single distance is truly 'in focus') and being 'acceptably in focus.'

Comment: Related: [Why I am getting different values for depth of field from calculators vs in-camera DoF preview?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/75471/15871)

Comment: Related: [Why did manufacturers stop including DOF scales on lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/64666/15871)

Comment: [How to focus on an area correctly, while still blurring everything else?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87862/15871)

Comment: [How do I set hyperfocal distance meter on a Pentax 50mm lens, if I want bokeh?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/83585/15871)

Comment: [Find hyperfocal distance for HD (1920x1080) resolution?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86786/15871)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I am getting different values for depth of field from calculators vs in-camera DoF preview?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/75471/why-i-am-getting-different-values-for-depth-of-field-from-calculators-vs-in-came)

Answer (score 1):

With the camera focus set to infinity (as far as the eye can see) the hyperlocal distance is the near subject distance that will render an object with acceptable focus. The far distance is infinity.

With the camera set to f/4 focused at infinity with a 35mm lens mounted -- the span of acceptable focus is 39 feet 7 inches thru to infinity.

Comment: ... assuming a display size of 8x10" viewed at a distance of 10" by a person with 20/20 vision. Change any of those parameters and the hyperfocal distance changes as well.

Comment: @ Michael Clark -- Assuming the hyperfocal distance given is correct for a specific application --- then if a camera is focused on infinity, that hperfocal distance will the near point in acceptable focus for that same application.

Comment: My comment above was specifically referring to the specific distance given in the last sentence of the answer: "With the camera set to f/4 focused at infinity with a 35mm lens mounted -- the span of acceptable focus is 39 feet 7 inches thru to infinity... *assuming a display size of 8x10" viewed at a distance of 10" by a person with 20/20 vision*."